# How to sum String values of an array, retrieved from checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, string, jsp, checkbox

I have certain JSP code, wherein I can select multiple checkboxes and then I am supposed to add the values of the selected elements.

However, due to the elements being retrieved are in String format, I get a `NumberFormatException` when I try to do this -

```
String chooseRight[] = request.getParameterValues("id");

if(chooseRight != null && chooseRight.length != 0){
    int sum =0;
         out.println("The sum is: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < chooseRight.length; i++) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(chooseRight[i]);
        out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

How can I possibly display `int` or `float` value in `out.print(sum);`?

Comment: Can you output Arrays.toString(chooseRight) and include it in your question?

Comment: Any progress on this? I'd still like to think my answer is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use typeof of to validate type in javascript such as

```
typeof "123"; // return string
typeof 123;// return number
typeof new Object(); // return object
```

Hope this info helped you out

Check out more about type checking in : http://www.avlabz.com/2013/01/geekyjs-javascript-strict-type-checking-plugin/

Comment: The code is java, not javascript. Not sure why the question is tagged with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the `out.println(sum);` that is the problem. `sum` is declared as an int and will stay that way. The error must happen in `Integer.parseInt()`, which in turn must be caused by `chooseRight` containing strings that can't be parsed as integers.

See [the docs for Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), which state:

> Throws:
>       NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

Comment: `chooseRight` contains int values. However, the returntype of  `request.getParameterValues()` is `String` which compelled me to declare `chooseRight` as String array. and Now I want to convert that to integer!

Comment: Yes, I understand, and you are doing it the right way, but Integer.parseInt() seems unable to parse those string values to integers. I mean it's not a problem that `chooseRight`contains strings, only that at least one of the strings it contains can't be parsed to an int.